# Video Streaming From Raspberry Pi zero using Arducam

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, video-streaming

I am trying to stream live video from Raspberry Pi zero using Arducam B0112.
I have written a function to stream video but the frame rate is low, Can you please suggest some alternative function to stream video and display it on localhost which will have better frame rate.

The video streaming function I have is as follows:

```
 def gen():
    """Video streaming generator function."""
    output = np.empty((240, 320, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    while True:  
        camera.capture(output, 'rgb')
        # Construct a numpy array from the stream
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', output, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 85])
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
```

Comment: how fast is camera? If it can't make images fast then you can't get fast stream.

Comment: @furas The specification of camera is "8MP IMX219 sensor with motorized focus lens". This link has all the details related to the camera "https://www.arducam.com/product/motorized-focus-8mp-camera-ov5647-sensor-raspberry-pimotorized-focus-5mp-camera-imx219-sensor-raspberry-pi/"

Comment: raspberry has special Python module for camera [picamera](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/). As I remember in examples you should see how to send stream by socket - without using Flask

Comment: Yes, I am using the picamera library @furas

Comment: you could also try programs like `ffmpeg` or `vlc` to stream it without `Flask`. See also on Raspberry Forum [How to stream video from Raspberry Pi camera and watch it live](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23182/how-to-stream-video-from-raspberry-pi-camera-and-watch-it-live)

Comment: BTW: to stream with motion detection I was using [motion](https://motion-project.github.io/)

Comment: Ok sure, let me give it a try. But I need it in flask in the later stage since the video stream will be accessed by a user.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208613/discussion-between-vishruti-and-furas).

Comment: in documentation for `picamera` you can see [web-streaming](https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.13/recipes2.html#web-streaming) which doesn't use `cv2` so maybe it will run faster.

Comment: ok sure I'll go through it. Thank you.